# a problem in with translating English into logical expressions

Tags: predicate, discrete-mathematics

- U = {fleegles, snurds, thingamabobs}
- F(x): x is a fleegle
- S(x): x is a snurd
- T(x): x is a thingamabob

If any fleegle is a snurd then it is also a thingamabob.

Solution:

[image]

I cannot understand the solution, why not write as （F(x)➡️S(x))➡️T（x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed solution implies things that are not stated; for instance, if some x is not a fleegle, F(x) => S(x) is true, and your statement then requires T(x), but we never said whether non-fleegles had to be thingamabobs.